# Different format of dataframe with 'loc' and 'to_frame'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I am running apply function on dataframe which has one row sometimes and there are two sources of dataframe. One is result of .loc and one is series converted to dataframe with to_frame().

The data is same in both of them. It's in a recursive function which with f1 as initial input and then queries inside function for df2 and call function again.

```
df1 = row.to_frame()
df2 = df3.loc[df3.loc['colname']== value]
```

Then, they go through same apply function as:

```
another_df = df1_or_df2.apply (lambda row:function (row))
```

above works fine with df1 but throws error for df2 `keyerror: ('id', 'occurred at index id')` for df2. If I add `axis=1`, then it works.

I did `try, except` to make it work as it is a one-off thing but need to improve the speed now.

Can you tell why the two formats of df are different or how I can do this more efficiently?

Comment: When you do `df.apply(func)`, `func` will be applied on columns of `df`, if you add `axis=1` then it applied to rows. You can try print out `df1` and `df2` to see why the code failed for one and succeeded for the other.

Comment: " how I can do this more efficiently" for this you have to add sample dataframes and expected output as text. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought `to_frame()` was converting the series to one row as I wanted but I think it was making one row for every column. So I did `df1 = row.to_frame().transpose()`. Now it works on both of them.

To make it more efficient, I had an attribute in the original dataframe to divide the data into subsets. So, now the whole function takes less time.

Thank you.